# Python List - change characters and keep the same order

Tags: python-3.x

I'm going to use the alphabet, to encrypt, can I make this change using list ?

> abc = abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz

I need to use the positions like this:
a = 1 b = 2 c = 3 d = 4...

> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10...]

I will change the positions with a function, changing the values, which will give me a result similar to this:

> b = [4, 23, 22, 11, 7, 8...]

then the letters would go to the positions of the first alphabet
a = 1 to 4, 4 = d, 23 = w, 22 = v...

> abc_2=dwvhk...

I intend to use it

```
from gi.module import maketrans

abc = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

abc_2 = 'dwvhkghevbwtrcmywqazxpolk'

encript = maketrans(abc,abc_2)

s = input('enter the phrase')
print (s.translate(encript))
```

Comment: what is your question? and there is [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20maketrans#str.maketrans) built-in; you do not need that import.

Comment: transform abc to abc_2, using b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a version:

```
# this is just to generate some permutation b
from random import shuffle
b = list(range(len(abc)))
shuffle(b)

abc = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
abc_2 = ''.join(abc[i] for i in b)
transtable = str.maketrans(abc, abc_2)
print('hello world'.translate(transtable))
```

for [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20maketrans#str.maketrans) to work the two given strings need to be of the same length.

your `abc_2` has some repeated letters and is one character shorter than the original alphabet...

Comment: I put variable 'abc'  before the variable 'b', I fix repeated letters and was missing 'f' caracter, thanks.worked perfect

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over `b` and get the char at position `abc` to construct `abc_2` like this:

```
abc = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz'
abc_2 = ''
new_index = [4, 23, 22, 11, 7, 8]

for x in range(len(new_index)):
    abc_2 += abc[new_index[x]]

print(abc_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```py
def maketrans(abc, abc_2):
  if len(abc) != len(abc_2):
    raise ValueError('strings should be the same length')
  trans = []
  for i in range(len(abc)):
    trans.append(ord(abc_2[i])-ord(abc[i]))
  return trans

def translate(s, encrypt):
  t = ""
  for i in range(len(s)):
    t += chr(ord(s[i])+encrypt[ord(s[i])-ord('a')])
  return t
```

Also, `abc_2` is missing a letter, I think it is 'f'.